# Limit reactivity scope to sub-document in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a mongo document structure as follows:

```
Gallery
--- Sub-Gallery
------ Image
------ Image
------ Image
--- Sub-Gallery
------ Image
------ Image
.
.
.
Gallery
.
.
.
```

I would like to represent it on screen. The naive implementation would be:

```
<name template="gallery">
{{#with get_specific_gallery_helper))
    {{#each sub_gallery}}
    This is a gallery {{name_sub_gallery}}
        {{#each image}}
            Something {{name_image}}
        {{/each}} 
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

The problem with this implantation is that every time a single image data changes the entire `Gallery` template is re-rendered.

**Is there a better way to do it?**

**Is it possible to limit the scope in every step?**

I would like to keep the db structure as is (no normalizing).

---

Why do I consider it a problem? 
First of all it simply does't make sense. Being more practical, I have specific event handlers that are invoked whenever a Gallery/Sub-Gallery/Image are rendered (e.g. fade in the images when loaded). Rendering everything all the time makes it much harder to handle these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider r[eactivity isolation](http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate):

```
<template name="gallery">
    {{#each sub_gallery}}
        {{#isolate}}
            This is a gallery {{name_sub_gallery}}
            {{#each image}}
                {{#isolate}}
                Something {{name_image}}
                {{/isolate}}
            {{/each}}
         {{/isolate}}        
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

This localizes changes in the isolate blocks to their own sort of planet so everything around them remains the same and untouched and it still remains reactive

You might have to test it with your document structure though, because each documents index may change when you update it if you store subitems with arrays instead of associative arrays with keys

Comment: But there is no data dependency in the `{{isolate block}}` the only dependency is at the top-level scope when fetching the entire document (See `with` clause after the edit). If I understand correctly then there is nothing to isolate in the `isolate` block.

Comment: Thats why I'm a bit unsure with your document structure, if you could just test it, it might be the indexes which cause it to re-render with the isolates, it'll look for changes in the objects too, it just pretends the stuff inside is in a different template

Comment: It should work if you edit the images, but i'm a bit unsure of when you add/remove an image (because some of the indexes change), but it wouldn't re-render the entire thing only the section where the arrays change

Comment: I had a problem similar to that, visit this discussion for more info [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/InbPsFGbfnU)